# SASL support in WSO2 Stream Processor / Siddhi

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, wso2, siddhi, sasl

Qs (1) Does Siddhi application support connecting to Kafka using SASL_SSL protocol with PLAIN as SASL Mechanism. 
Qs (2) If not what SASL options are available. I am using WSO2 Streaming Processor 4.4.

Below is a simple program that's expected to read from a Kafka topic and write the content as is on server console.

Note-1: The connections establishes just fine (Deployment on worker node is also successful). But nothing reflected on console.

Note:2: The program runs just fine if connected to a non secure Kafka cluster (I remove the optional.configuration and change the bootstrap servers value appropriately)

```
@App:name("SKAppOne")  
@source(  
type='kafka',   
topic.list='skapp1',   
group.id='g1',  
partition.no.list='0',  
threading.option='single.thread',  
bootstrap.servers='**KAFKABROKERIP:KAFKABROKERPORT**',   
optional.configuration=  
***"sasl.mechanism:PLAIN,security.protocol:SASL_SSL,***  
sasl.jaas.config:org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='**validuserid**' password='**validpassword**';,  
ssl.truststore.location:**validlocationfor_client.truststore.jks file**,    
ssl.truststore.password:**validpassword**,    
ssl.keystore.location:**validlocationfor_server.keystore.jks file**,    
ssl.keystore.password:**validpassword**,    
ssl.key.password:**validpassword**",         
@map(type='json'))  

define stream InputStreamFromSecureKafka (name string, location string);


@sink(type='log')  
define stream SOutputStreamToConsole (name string, location string);  

@info(name='kafkatosconsole')   
from InputStreamFromSecureKafka  
select *  
insert into SOutputStreamToConsole;
```